# Lucene TermFrequenciesVector

Tags: java, vector, lucene

what do I obtain if I call `IndexReader.getTermFrequenciesVector(...)` on an index created with `TermVector.YES` option?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have a specific question that the [docs](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_1_0/api/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) don't answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) already answers this, as Xodorap notes in a comment.

The `TermFreqVector` object returned can retrieve which terms (words produced by your analyzer) a field contains and how many times each of those terms exists within that field.

You can cast the returned `TermFreqVector` to the interface `TermPositionVector` if you index the field using `TermVector.WITH_OFFSETS`, `TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS` or `TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS`. This gives you access to `GetTermPositions` with allow you to check where in the field the term exists, and `GetOffsets` which allows you to check where in *the original content* the term originated from. The later allows, combined with `Store.YES`, highlighting of matching terms in a search query.

There are different contributed highlighters available under Contrib area found at [the Lucene homepage](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can implement proximity or first occurrence type score contributions. Which highlighting won't help you with at all.